# How to account for neighboring cells in a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

**Prompt:** 
Given a 2D integer matrix M representing the gray scale of an image, you need to design a smoother to make the gray scale of each cell becomes the average gray scale (rounding down) of all the 8 surrounding cells and itself. If a cell has less than 8 surrounding cells, then use as many as you can.

**Example:**

*Input:*

**[[1,1,1],**

**[1,0,1],**

**[1,1,1]]**

*Output:*

**[[0, 0, 0],**

**[0, 0, 0],**

**[0, 0, 0]]**

*Explanation:*

```
For the point (0,0), (0,2), (2,0), (2,2) -> floor(3/4) = floor(0.75) = 0
For the point (0,1), (1,0), (1,2), (2,1) ->  floor(5/6) = floor(0.83333333) = 0
For the point (1,1): floor(8/9) = floor(0.88888889) = 0
```

**Solution:**

```
class Solution:
    def imageSmoother(self, grid):
        """
        :type M: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])

        #Go through each cell 
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):

            #Metrics for calculating average, starting inputs are zero since the loop includes the current cell, grid[r][c]

            total = 0
            n = 0

            #Checking the neighbors
            for ri in [-1,0,1]:
                for ci in [-1,0,1]:
                    if (r + ri >= 0 and r + ri <= rows-1 and c + ci >=0 and c + ci <= cols-1):
                        total += grid[r+ri][c+ci]
                        n += 1 

            #Now we convert the cell value to the average 
            grid[r][c] = int(total/n)

        return grid
```

My solution is incorrect. It passes some test cases, but for this one I fail.

*Input:* **[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[11,12,13],[14,15,16]]**

*Output:* **[[4,4,5],[6,6,6],[8,9,9],[11,11,12],[12,12,12]]**

*Expected:* **[[4,4,5],[5,6,6],[8,9,9],[11,12,12],[13,13,14]]**

As you can see, my solution is really close. I'm not sure where I'm messing up since when I changed the parameters around I started failing other basic test cases. The solutions I see online use other packages which I'd prefer not to use since I want to approach this problem more intuitively.

How do you check where you're going wrong with 2D array problems? Thanks!

**Leetcode solution:**

```
def imageSmoother(self, M):
        R,C=len(M),len(M[0])
        M2=[[0]*C for i in range(R)]
        for i in range(R):
            for j in range(C):
                temp=[M[i+x][j+y] for x,y in list(itertools.product([-1,0,1],[-1,0,1])) if 0<=i+x<R and 0<=j+y<C ]
                M2[i][j]=(sum(temp)//len(temp))
        return M2
```

Comment: I know you say "The solutions I see online use other packages which I'd prefer not to use since I want to approach this problem more intuitively", but really, using NumPy or another package that gives you 2D arrays as a thing, rather than forcing you to think of them in terms of lists of lists and indexing and slicing and comprehensions, is usually _more_ intuitive, not less. (I'm not saying it's not worth figuring out how to solve problems like this with lists of lists, because sometimes you're going to have to do things like that—just don't unnecessarily solve every problem that way.)

Comment: By the way, your initial example is not all that helpful—if you only have integer values 0 and 1, every cell ends up with 0 unless all of its neighbors are 1. If you instead explained why you expected a few of the expected values in your test case, that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: @abarnert
So, I ran my code through leetcode and that was their example. I also edited my post to include the Leetcode solution. Here's the link if you're interested. https://leetcode.com/problems/image-smoother/description/

Comment: In case you're interested in exploring NumPy: Instead of looping over rows and columns and then over the 9 directions for each pixel, you just shift the whole grid in each of the 9 directions, and mean the resulting 9 arrays. You can write this manually in a few lines, or as a one-liner with `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`. Would you be interested in seeing either solution, or are you happy with the loop one?

Comment: @abarnert
Thanks a bunch! I think the one-liner should suffice. I want to get in the habit of writing efficient clean code! Thanks so much for taking the time to thoroughly educate me

Comment: Now you've put me on the spot, because I don't have `scipy` on my tablet… but I can edit my answer with something that I'm _pretty sure_ is right, and if I'm wrong, let me know…

Comment: Actually, never mind; `repl.it` has SciPy. :)

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why the leetcode answer does `list(product(…))` instead of just looping over the `product` directly. It doesn't matter much when there's only 3*3 values, but still, why make it more complicated, and why make an already ridiculously long expression go even farther off the right edge of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're modifying `grid` as you go along. So, for each cell, you're using the input values for the down/right neighbors, but the output values for the up/left neighbors.

So, for your given example, when you're computing the neighbors of `grid[1][0]`, you've already replaced two of the neighbors, `grid[0][0]` and `grid[0][1]`, so they're now `4, 4` instead of `2, 3`. Which means you're averaging `4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9` instead of `2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9`. So, instead of getting a 5.5 that you round down to 5, you get a 6.0 that you round down to 6.

---

The simplest fix is to just build up a new output grid as you go along, then return that:

```
    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    outgrid = []
    #Go through each cell 
    for r in range(rows):
        outrow = []
        for c in range(cols):
            # … same code as before, but instead of the grid[r][c] =
            outrow.append(int(total/n))
        outgrid.append(outrow)
    return outgrid
```

---

If you need to modify the grid in place, you can instead copy the original grid, and iterate over that copy:

```
    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    ingrid = [list(row) for row in grid]
    #Go through each cell 
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            # … same code as before, but instead of total += grid[r+ri][c+ci]
            total += ingrid[r+ri][c+ci]
```

---

If you used a 2D [NumPy](https://numpy.org) array instead of a list of lists, you could solve this at a higher level.

NumPy lets you add entire arrays all at once, divide them by scalars, etc., so you can get rid of those loops over `r` and `c` and just do the work array-wide. But you still have to think about your boundaries. You can't just add `arr` and `arr[:-1]` and `arr[1:]` and so on, you need to pad them out to the same size. And if you just pad with 0s, you'll end up averaging `0, 4, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9`, which is no good. But if you pad them with `NaN` values, so you're averaging `NaN, 4, 4, NaN, 5, 6, NaN, 8, 9`, then you can use the [`nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) function, which ignores those `NaN` values and averages the 6 real values.

So, this is still a few lines of code to iterate over the 9 directions, pad the 9 arrays, and `nanmean` the results. (Or you could cram it into a giant expression with `product`, like the leetcode answer, but that isn't exactly more readable or easier to understand.)

But if you can drag in [`SciPy`](https://scipy.org/), a collection of algorithms for almost anything you'd ever want to build on top of NumPy, it has a function in its [`ndimage`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/ndimage.html) library called [`generic_filter`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) that can do every conceivable variation of "gather the N neighbors, padding like X, and run function Y on the resulting arrays".

In our case, we want to gather the 3-per-axis neighbors, pad with the constant value NaN, and run the `nanmean` function, so [this one-liner will do everything you need](https://repl.it/repls/EcstaticVillainousParallelcompiler):

```
scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(grid, function=np.nanmean, size=3, mode='constant', cval=np.NaN)
```